# How to store a two-register mul result into memory

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

So let's say that I've got a result of `mul` in `dx:ax`, how can I save it to `dword [ebx]`??

I have the same problem with double words : edx (high half) and eax (low half) to two dwords pointed to by `[ebx]`.

Comment: Use two `mov`s: `mov [ebx], ax` / `mov [ebx+2], dx`

Comment: This should be an answer.

Comment: And what about eax and edx ?? +4 ?

Comment: Yes, `mov [ebx],eax` will store 32 bits (eax = 32b register) (= 4 bytes) into memory, so if you want to have the edx value right after it, you can use [ebx+4] to address those following 4 bytes. Just keep in mind, you have to have ebx pointing to some memory, where you have this size (8 bytes) reserved, otherwise you will overwrite something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by commenters Michael and Ped7g already, you have use offsets. Let me explain:

x86 stores numbers in little-endian format, meaning that the lowest-order bytes are stored first in memory. A little example: Assuming you have the value `0x12345678` in `eax`, and you execute this instruction:

```
mov [addr], eax
```

...then the memory at address `addr` will look like this:

```
78 56 34 12
```

In your example, you have a value in `dx:ax` which is a shorthand for "have a value's upper 16 bits in `dx` and its lower 16 bits in `ax`". Assuming the value is, again, `0x12345678`, so you have `0x1234` in `dx` and `0x5678` in `ax`, then you need two move instructions:

```
mov [addr], ax   // Memory now looks like this: 78 56
mov [addr+2], dx // Memory now looks like this: 78 56 34 12
```

The `+2` comes from the fact that `ax` is a 16-bit register, i.e. it uses up two bytes when stored in memory, so since you want to put `dx` right after it, you need to increase the address by `2`.

Same thing for 64-bit values in `edx` and `eax`, with an offset `4`. Let's assume you have the value `0x1234567890ABCDEF` split to `0x12345678` in `edx` and `0x90ABCDEF` in `eax`, then it would look like this:

```
mov [addr], eax   // Memory now looks like this: EF CD AB 90
mov [addr+4], edx // Memory now looks like this: EF CD AB 90 78 56 34 12
```

Comment: (MASM/TASM will need `mov dword ptr [addr], eax` if `addr` is defined with a `dq` qword.)