# how to extract content from DX:AX after multiplication of two 16 bits register for further calculation? 8086 assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am using DOSBOX 0.74 to write 8086 assembly code

I plan to multiply two 2-bytes numbers to produce a very large number.
3333 X 999=3,329,667

The value will be stored in DX:AX. My question is how can the product of the multiplication be retrieved and stored into a single memory or register, so i can perform additional arithmetic calculation such as division on this value.

I have done a little bit of research. I have seen people recommended the use of push and pop, but i am not certain it is used.

My code is as follow:

```
num1 db 3333
num2 db 999
mov ax, num1
mov bx, num2
mul bx
```

; i am stuck here...

Comment: If you can use 32-bit registers (i.e. 16-bit code that will only run on a 386 or later), use a 32-bit `imul eax, ebx` in the first place after zero or sign-extending your numbers into EAX and EBX (or whatever regs you want).  If you can't use 32-bit registers, then there's no way to fit a 32-bit number into one register.  Use extended-precision techniques like `adc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store a two-register mul result into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37250232), except this asks for the impossible of combining the result into one register (only possible with a 32-bit register).

Answer (score 3):

The essential part of Ped7g's answer if you want the result in a `dd var 0` dword in memory:

```
mov word ptr [var], ax
mov word ptr [var+2], dx
```

the values will be merged in the variable `var`

Comment: The question mentions storing them into one *register*, so it's confused about how numbers work / how big a register is, and needed the longer answer.  But yes, for future readers that just wanted to store into a dword memory variable, it's a duplicate of [How to store a two-register mul result into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37250232) which has an answer like this.  But if google pointed them here instead, this answer is helpful I guess.

Answer (score 2):

> how to extract content from DX:AX ...

Well, the content is in them, you don't need to extract it any way. If you would multiply smaller values, where result does fit into 16 bits only, like 123 * 45 = 5535, then `dx = 0, ax = 5535` after `mul`.

In your example (after fixing `num1/num2` definition) you are doing 3333 * 999 = 3329667, which is in binary: 0000_0000_0011_0010_1100_1110_1000_0011 and these 32 bits are just like that stored in `dx:ax`, i.e. `dx = 0000_0000_0011_0010 = 0032h = 50` and `ax = 1100_1110_1000_0011 = 0CE83h = 52867`. (and 50 * 2<sup>16</sup> + 52867 = 3329667).

There's nothing to "extract" from that, it's already 32 bit integer, ready to be used for further calculation.

---

Sort of fix of your code with comments trying to explain what I show:

```
data:
num1 dw 3333       ; fixed to "dw" to define word (16b)
num2 dw 999
mulResult dd 0     ; reserve 32 bits of memory

code:
mov ax, [num1]
mov bx, [num2]
mul bx             ; dx:ax = ax * bx
; store 32 bits into memory (in little-endian way)
mov [mulResult],ax
mov [mulResult+2],dx
; now you can load it back into 32b register on 80386+ CPUs:
mov eax,[mulResult]
; or if you are on 8086-80286 CPU, you can load it back into dx:ax pair
; by loading the 16 bit parts separately
mov ax,[mulResult]
mov dx,[mulResult+2]
mov bx,10000
div bx   ; ax = dx:ax / bx (quotient), dx = remainder
```

---

The `dx` and `ax` are 16 bit registers. They are set after the [`mul`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html) to contain upper and lower 16 bits of 32 bit result.

You can't store it into single (16b) register, or into single word memory (will not fit). You must store all 32 bits somewhere.

Also your source in question does `num1 db 3333`, but `3333` doesn't fit into byte (needs at least 12 bits to be encoded in simple "unsigned integer" encoding), so after assembling you have value `5` at address `num1`, not `3333`.

Then `mov ax, [num1]` will load two bytes, not one...

Pay attention how information is encoded in computer, how binary 0/1 value of single bit can be used to encode different values, like integers, floats, strings, etc... And what are the common "types" and information encodings.