# How to fit qword into eax and edx register?

Tags: assembly, x86

This is my code:

```
mov    eax, qword ptr qword1+0
mov    edx, qword ptr qword1+4
```

I run into an error when trying to do this. I want to figure out how I can fit `qword1` into the above registers. I am new to x86 Assembly, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The two halves of a qword are each dword.  e.g. [Print a qword stored in eax:ebx x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41128159) / [How to store a two-register mul result into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37250232)

Comment: Are you going share what the error is?

Answer (score 3):

Your *qword1* variable is probably defined using the `dq` directive:

```
qword1  dq ...
```

If you're using an assembler that 'remembers' the size of your variables, then writing `mov eax, qword1` will trigger an error about mismatching sizes. Even so for writing `mov eax, qword ptr qword1 + 0` where sizes are also mismatched (dword vs qword).

You will need to override the size that the assembler knows about and use the same size as the register that you want to load:

```
mov     eax, dword ptr qword1
mov     edx, dword ptr qword1 + 4
```